# uml / class design tool for Python?

Tags: python

I am looking for an open source, easy to use tool that will help me design and get a quick sense of a single class' outline (member variables, public/private methods, what they do etc).

Can you recommend on any such tools?

I am looking for a tool that can work under `Linux` environment.

If possible, such a tool should somehow integrate with `Python`.

Comment: Python **is** a design tool. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Elclipse pyuml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-pyuml/). It is open source and ran as plugin of eclipse. Therefore, it should be fine in Linux.